# MSVC struct layout changes when wrapping flexible array in anonymous struct?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, flexible-array-member, anonymous-struct

I'm looking at layout info for the following structs [using godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/5lJ95v):

```
struct Foo1 {
    int size;
    void *data[];
};

struct Foo2 {
    int size;
    struct {
        void *data[];
    };
};
```

I'd expected the layout for both structs `Foo1` and `Foo2` to be the same. From what I understand, any fields of an anonymous nested struct are simply "folded" into the parent struct. So the layout of `Foo2` should turn out the same as that of `Foo1`.

However, the layouts generated by MSVC 19.16, and displayed when using the flag `/d1reportSingleClassLayoutFoo` differ:

```
class Foo1  size(8):
    +---
 0  | size
    | <alignment member> (size=4)
 8  | data
    +---
class Foo2  size(16):
    +---
 0  | size
    | <alignment member> (size=4)
    | <anonymous-tag> <alignment member> (size=8)
 8  | data
    | <alignment member> (size=7)
    +---
```

`Foo2` is double the size of `Foo1`. And `data` suddenly seems to have a size of 1 byte.

There are some warning generated with `-Wall`:

```
warning C4200: nonstandard extension used: zero-sized array in struct/union
note: This member will be ignored by a defaulted constructor or copy/move assignment operator
warning C4820: 'Foo1': '4' bytes padding added after data member 'Foo1::size'
warning C4200: nonstandard extension used: zero-sized array in struct/union
note: This member will be ignored by a defaulted constructor or copy/move assignment operator
warning C4820: 'Foo2::<anonymous-tag>': '7' bytes padding added after data member 'Foo2::data'
warning C4201: nonstandard extension used: nameless struct/union
warning C4820: 'Foo2': '4' bytes padding added after data member 'Foo2::size'
```

But none of these seem to explain the difference in layout, or hint towards undefined behavior. And, neither does the doc: [Anonymous structs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/cpp/anonymous-class-types?view=vs-2017#microsoft-specific).

For the record, I do know that this code is relying on MSVC extensions:

```
warning C4200: nonstandard extension used: zero-sized array in struct/union
warning C4201: nonstandard extension used: nameless struct/union
```

The "zero-sized array" `data` seems to be a flexible array member, since putting it before the `size` field throws an error.

Why do the layouts of `Foo1` and `Foo2` differ?

Comment: "From what I understand, any fields of an anonymous nested struct are simply "folded" into the parent struct" Do you have a reference to motivate that assumption?

Comment: @Frank Tbh, this is mostly based on observation from using the debug flags, and the fact that you can access the nested field through the parent struct directly in the language. I haven't found a good reference on how layouts are generated by MSVC yet. Is my assumption a false premise? FWIW, [GCC does seem to generate the same layout for both types.](https://godbolt.org/z/lWedNf)

Comment: You are "kinda" correct in the sense that you can expect consistent layouts  between two types if they are [layout-compatible](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/data_members#Standard_layout). This is not the case between your two types, so compilers are allowed to do what they want. If it works on a given compiler, then it's just luck.

Comment: @Frank Ok, my assumption that `Foo1` and `Foo2` will have the same layout fails, as evidenced also by the output from the compiler. But I'd like to know the reason why there is a difference on MSVC specifically.

Comment: What's the layout of a struct that only has the void pointer? I'd halfway guess that that is similar to the struct with just a void pointer nested inside another struct, for layout-compatibility.

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt They are not the same size: https://godbolt.org/z/AUddUv

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your anonymous struct is a distinct type.  As such, it cannot have a zero size, and therefore has a size of 1 byte.  `data` still has a zero size, but the struct that contains it does not.